# How to install couchbase in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, community

I am facing an issue in installing Couchbase community edition server in my Ubuntu 14 machine.
`uname -a` output

```
3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded debian `couchbase-server-community_2.2.0_x86_64.deb` and when i running this using `dpkg -i` it gives me an error Invalid package.

Need suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the couchbase server package for ubuntu 12.04 64 bits Community Edition version 3.0.1 from http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads and it works fine as of this writing on ubuntu 14.04.

I haven't done much with it other than the nodejs tutorial on http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/introduction.html , so maybe if you're doing advanced stuff you might run into issues.

But if like me you just want to check out couchbase, this is much easier.

I don't recommend building from source because it takes much longer, and also you will need to write a bash script to run couchbase as a daemon. Too much hassle so I went with the package from couchbase and it worked out of the box.